# Onclick Event takes 4-5 second to launch next activity

Tags: android, onclick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(Shkey.prefMain, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnApprove) {
        Log.e("method", methods);
        editor.putString(Shkey.shStatus, Shkey.shSuccess).apply();
        if (methods.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.stPinCode))) {
            intent = new Intent(ValidationRequest.this, PinCode.class);
            intent.putExtra(Inkey.inSource, Inkey.iValidationRequest);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (methods.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.stFingerprint))) {
            ec.doGenerateOtp(context, AppPreferencesStore.getValue(context, Shkey.shPinCode),
                    AppPreferencesStore.getValue(context, Shkey.shChallangeString));
            intent = new Intent(ValidationRequest.this, FingerPrintSuccess.class);
            intent.putExtra(Inkey.inSource, Inkey.iValidationRequest);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (methods.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.stFacial))) {
            Log.e("start", "facial");
//                ec.doGenerateOtp(context, AppPreferencesStore.getValue(context, Shkey.shPinCode),
//                        AppPreferencesStore.getValue(context, Shkey.shChallangeString));
            intent = new Intent(ValidationRequest.this, FacialVerification3.class);
            intent.putExtra(Inkey.inSource, Inkey.iValidationRequest);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just try calling another empty activity. if it takes less time then you need to optimize your actual activity as it might be doing some heavy tasks

Comment: Thank you for your support, but i already tried this...my problem is : heavy initialization is in my second Activity though why my first activity take too much time to redirect to the second one??